# Calculate a metric based on two tables in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, relationship, dax

Within my model I need to calculate a measure based on two related tables. The schema would be something like this:

[image]

[image]

On the table A I need to calculate a new metric called Bonus (Revenue*%bonus).

[image]

I'm kind of new with this tool, and I have seen a possible solution but so sure to understand it properly. What should I do, create the metric on the dashboard or in PowerBi?

I would appreciate any help.

Regards,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a relationship between Table A and Table B on the `Contract_type` column, then you can create the `Bonus` calculated column simply as

```
Bonus = TableA[Revenue] * RELATED( TableB[%bonus] )
```

If you need this as a measure, then put it inside a `SUMX`:

```
Bonus = SUMX ( TableA, TableA[Revenue] * RELATED( TableB[%bonus] ) )
```

Comment: Hi @Alexis. I have tried. But for some reason when creating the metric in table A on the dashboard PowerBI does not show me table B. Even writing the formula as you did, I'm always getting an error, and the relation does not have any problem. This is the version of power BI desktop I'm using Version: 2.65.5313.1562

Comment: You can't write what I did as a measure. It only works as a calculated column the way I wrote it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. It was very useful.